# How to set up an automatic versioning on TortoiseSVN?

Tags: c#, svn, tortoisesvn

I am trying to set up an auto-versioning update on TortoiseSVN for a project I'm working on. It's very straightforward; the code is supposed to pull the SVN revision and display the date & location whenever anyone does a checkout/update from the repo.

Below I have a template class

```
    public static class SvnRevision
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// SVN repo revision
        /// </summary>
        public const string REVISION = "$WCREV$";

        /// <summary>
        /// SVN repo location
        /// </summary>
        public const string REPOSITORY_URL = @"$WCURL$";

        /// <summary>
        /// SVN repo date
        /// </summary>
        public const string REPOSITORY_DATE = "$WCDATE$";
    }
```

I want to know the background steps necessary to get this program to work. Appreciate if anyone could provide a walk through or tutorial. I am trying to do this on Visual Studio 2022.

I made commits using this class to SVN without any luck, a search indicates that I need to set up versioning and provide some kind of source/destination files that I don't know how to do. Below is a link I've referenced.

https://docs.huihoo.com/tortoisesvn/1.5.7-en/tsvn-subwcrev-keywords.html

Comment: Consider code generation on your ci server. That way it’s portable out of your source control

Comment: https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html. In particular, you need to set the `svn:keywords` property on that file, see the example on that page. Also note that the placeholders on that page are different to the ones you'se using -- I'm not sure where yours come from, but the ones on that page are the ones I've used before

Comment: @canton7 - subwcrev tool and svn-keywords are different things, don't mix it!

Comment: @LazyBadger Looks like OP wants svn-keywords from their description? Or maybe not, it's not clear to me

Comment: @canton7 - no, I see **repo**-specific requirements, not file-specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the help everyone. Likely my line of questioning was not clear or I worked it wrong, but the problem was that I needed to set a command line as a prebuild event so that the SVN keywords would update.

Prebuild event command line: *"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\SubWCRev.exe" "$(ProjectDir)." "$(ProjectDir)SvnRevision_Template.cs" "$(ProjectDir)SvnRevision.cs"*

Answer (score 2):

Before selecting **The Right Thing (tm)** for your task and|or using SubWCRev (which you try to use, according to used subwcrev-specific keywords) you have to know some things

1. **Best** (and, really, single correct place) for reading updated, relevant to latest release docs about SubWCRev is [TortoiseSVN website](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-subwcrev.html) (SubWCRev is part of TortoiseSVN distribution and **is not** of *pure SVN* per se)
2. "...whenever anyone does a checkout/update from the repo" such person with WC of your repo have *more natural way* to know, which revision he|she got and whence: ordinary [`svn info`](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.info.html) tells it, instead of reading your code or compiling it in order to see message-box with collected data
3. Contrary to SVN-keywords, which work from a box (when inserted into files) and updated automagically on the fly, subwcrev's keywords have to have "release" stage (read [docs](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-subwcrev.html#tsvn-subwcrev-cli)): you insert keywords in template-file, which, after processing by SubWCRev, will produce **new file**, in which template-placeholders are replaced by data, actual only for this moment and not updated automatically after WC-changes (you must to refresh files from templates again)

In your case you can

- move `public static class SvnRevision` into `somename.cs.tpl` with all needed keywords
- **Before** all other steps in your compile-chain add call of SubWCRev, smth.like `SubWCRev.exe path\to\WC somename.cs.tpl somename.cs`
- In you code use references to `somename.cs`, which also have to be in svn-ignore and not versioned, while template have to be versioned

HTH